# How to show that $\mathbb{Z}$ with the operation $m*n=m+(-1)^m n$ is associative?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm reading Beardon's *Algebra and Geometry*:

> Show that $\mathbb{Z}$ with the operation $m*n=m+(-1)^m n$, is a group.

I've been thinking on how I should show associativity, I thought about doing this:

$$(m*n)*p$$

Then assuming:

$$m*n=m+(-1)^m n$$

I have:

$$(m+(-1)^m n)*p$$

Which results in:

$$[m+(-1)^m n]+(-1)^{[m+(-1)^m n]}p$$

Then:

$$m*(n*p)$$

Again, assuming that:

$$n*p=n+(-1)^n p$$

I have:

$$m*(n+(-1)^n p)$$

Then:

$$m+(-1)^m [n+(-1)^n p]$$

And show that:

$$[m+(-1)^m n]+(-1)^{[m+(-1)^m n]}p=m+(-1)^m [n+(-1)^n p]\tag{A} $$

But I've tested it with some values on Mathematica and found that when:

$$m = 1;
n = 0;
p = -1;$$

The equality does not hold. I'm stuck again. Can you please provide me some hints on how to do it? I'm not looking for a full answer.

---

When I was testing the equality on Mathematica, I felt that permutations of $m,n,p$ on the set $\{-1,0,1\}$ could be enough to prove it, for example:

$$\begin {array} { c | c | c }
m,n,p & m,n,p & m,n,p \\
\hline
  -1, -1, -1 & - 1, -1, 0 & - 1, -1, 1  \\
  -1, 0, -1 & - 1, 0, 0 & - 1, 0, 1  \\
  -1, 1, -1 & - 1, 1, 0 & - 1, 1, 1  \\
  0, -1, -1 & 0, -1, 0 & 0, -1, 1  \\
  0, 0, -1 & 0, 0, 0 & 0, 0, 1  \\
  0, 1, -1 & 0, 1, 0 & 0, 1, 1  \\
  1, -1, -1 & 1, -1, 0 & 1, -1, 1  \\
  1, 0, -1 & 1, 0, 0 & 1, 0, 1  \\
  1, 1, -1 & 1, 1, 0 & 1, 1, 1  \\
\end {array} $$

But I'm not sure if this is true. What do you think?

Comment: You must have entered things wrong in setting up the formula. Both sides evaluate to $2$, if $(m,n,p)=(1,0,-1)$ and one defines $f(x,y)=x+(-1)^x y$ etc.

Comment: @coffeemath Yes. I've spotted the typo now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use the equality $(-1)^{m+(-1)^m n}=(-1)^{m+ n}$.

Answer (score 1):

Using $(-1)^n=(-1)^{-n}$:
$$[m+(-1)^m n]+(-1)^{[m+(-1)^m n]}p=m+(-1)^mn+(-1)^{m+n}p=m+(-1)^m [n+(-1)^n p] $$

Answer (score 1):

Your left hand side evaluates to:

$m + (-1)^m n + (-1)^{m + (-1)^m n}p$

and your right hand side evaluates to:

$m + (-1)^m n + (-1)^{m+n}p$

After eliminating the common terms:

$m + (-1)^m n$ from both sides, we are left with showing:

$(-1)^{m+(-1)^m n}p = (-1)^{m+n}p$

If $p = 0$, both sides are clearly equal, so assume $p \neq 0$, and we can (by cancellation) simply prove:

$(-1)^{(-1)^m n} = (-1)^n$.

It should be clear that if $m$ is even, we have equality (both sides are $(-1)^n$), so we are down to the case where $m$ is odd. In this case:

$(-1)^{(-1)^m n} = (-1)^{-n} = \frac{1}{(-1)^n}$

Multiplying both sides by $(-1)^n$ then yields:

$1 = (-1)^{2n} = [(-1)^n]^2$ which is always true, no matter what $n$ is.